# How to match either but not both in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to match these possible flags: `[-ASC|-BIN] [-REC] [-DEL]`
They are all optional, but with the `-ASC` and `-BIN` flags they are xor'd only one of them can be used, not both.

Here is the grammar I have for handling the flags: `(GET_OPTION_ASC | GET_OPTION_BIN) | GET_OPTION_REC | GET_OPTION_DEL | SPACES;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule that ASC and BIN many not appear together is not a syntactic decision, but a semantic one. The parser can only execute syntactic tasks.

Usually, you have a semantic phase after parsing for various other tasks, not related to syntax. This is one of them. You should examine the built parse tree and report errors on all semantic errors (like duplicate variable names, the one you mentioned above etc.).